# Drop rows in dataframe whose column has more than a certain number of distinct values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataframe as given below, and am trying to drop the rows where the column `cluster_num` has only 1 distinct value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,4,2,5],[1,3,7,9,10],[2,6,2,7,9],[2,2,4,7,0],[3,1,9,2,7],[4,9,5,1,2],[5,8,4,2,1],[5,0,7,1,2],[6,9,2,5,7]])
df.rename(columns = {0:"cluster_num",1:"value_1",2:"value_2",3:"value_3",4:"value_4"},inplace=True)

# Dropping rows for which cluster_num has only one distinct value
count_dict = df['cluster_num'].value_counts().to_dict()
df['count'] = df['cluster_num'].apply(lambda x : count_dict[x])
df[df['count']>1]
```

In the above example, the rows where `cluster_num` equals 3,4 and 6 would be dropped.

Is there a way of doing this without having to create a separate column? I need all 5 initial columns (cluster_num, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4) in the output. My output dataframe according to the above code is :

[image]

I have tried to filter using `groupby()` with `count()` but it was not working out.

Comment: `df[df.groupby('cluster_num')['cluster_num'].transform('size') >= thresh]` or in the case `thresh=1`: `df[df['cluster_num'].duplicated(keep=False)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `groupby`/`filter`

```
df.groupby('cluster_num').filter(lambda d: len(d) > 1)
```

---

#### `duplicated`

```
df[df.duplicated('cluster_num', keep=False)]
```

---

#### `groupby`/`transform`

Per [@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788096/drop-rows-in-dataframe-whose-column-has-more-than-a-certain-number-of-distinct-v/66788139#comment118061409_66788096)

```
df[df.groupby('cluster_num')['cluster_num'].transform('size') >= 2]
```